# How to preserve data in array from Ionic - this.array.push is not a function

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, storage

The array `storedArr = []` is used to store data using storage, however, I receive the `.push is not a function` when I try to fill it with the storage get method:

```
storedArr = this.storage.get('stored') ? this.storage.get('stored').then((e) => {e}) : [];
```

The esencial part of my code is:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyPage {
    constructor(
        private storage: Storage) {
    }

    // storedArr = []; This works but resets the array

    storedArr = this.storage.get('stored') ? this.storage.get('stored').then((e) => {e}) : [];

    saveToStorage() {
        this.storedArr.push({ // .push is not a function
          title: 'blabla',
          body: 'more blabla'
        });

        this.storage.set('stored', this.storedArr);
    }
}
```

How should I write that part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

The Ionic `this.storage.get` actually doesn't return any value other then a promise which then has to be "subscribed" to.

So `storedArr = this.storage.get('stored') ? this.storage.get('stored').then((e) => {e}) : [];` on success actually stores a promise inside `storedArr` then on fail it still returns a promise. Hence the error - because `Promise.prototype` does not contain the `push` method. So the ternary operator will evaluate to `true` and so `[]` will **not** be assigned to `storedArr`.

In order to get the value of the Ionic `this.storage.get('stored')` you have to "subscribe" to the returned promise and then assign the `data` parameter to `storedArr`. Like so...

```
export class MyPage {
  storedArr = [];

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
      this.storage.get('stored')
          .then(data => {
            this.storedArr = data;
          });
  }

  saveToStorage() {
      this.storedArr.push({ // .push is not a function
        title: 'blabla',
        body: 'more blabla'
      });

      this.storage.set('stored', this.storedArr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer made me notice I could have written my initial code this way: storedArr = this.storage.get('stored') ? this.storage.get('stored').then(e => this.storedArr = e) : [];

Comment: yea would've worked. but that's weird  and it becomes that much harder to read & understand. rather move the "subscribing" to `ngInit()` (Angular's recommendation) or the constructor (like I showed you in the answer).

Comment: oh I've slightly clarified the answer. please read it again (the solution remains unchanged though).

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing something other than a simple primitive value, you'll likely need to do a `JSON.parse()` on the storage getter result.  Something like below.  I adjusted to use await (in place of your `then`s), which I think is much clearer.

```
var storageResult = await this.storage.get('stored');
storedArr = (storageResult) ? JSON.parse(storageResult) : [];
```

Additionally, when you store the array you likely want to do a `JSON.stringify` on it.

```
this.storage.set('stored', JSON.stringify(this.storedArr));
```